# Strange behaviour when casting Enum

Tags: c#, enums, cil

I have an enum:

```
public enum Blah
{
    Value  = 0,
    Value2 = 1
}
```

And the following code:

```
void Main()
{
    Blah? a = Blah.Value;
    bool val = (a == (int) Blah.Value);  // compiles
         val = (a == (int) Blah.Value2); // doesn't compile
}
```

As you can see from the comments above, the first line compiles but the second doesn't.

Can anyone explain it? I checked the *IL Interpreter* and can't really see why:

[image]

Comment: What compilation error are you seeing?

Comment: remove the nullable, still the same

Comment: change Value to any non zero number and it will also fail on the "compiles" line

Comment: @KeithNicholas: Yes I am aware of that...but why?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: The image now shows the error I get

Comment: Perfect, I thought it was something to do with implicit casting, couldn't find the other one on SO, thanks @KeithNicholas